# Rotating in canvas without moving all other objects?

Tags: canvas, rotation

I'm trying to make a 2-player tank game with two tanks that shoot at each other using the keyboard to control them. I've got the forward and backward movement for both, but when I've tried rotating them it rotates the other as well. (At the moment the tanks are just rectangles.)

**How can I rotate one without moving the other?**

```
var draw;
var context;
var DKey = false;
var AKey = false;
var WKey = false;
var SKey = false;
var tank1_x;
var tank1_y;
var tank1_w = 30;
var tank1_h = 30;
var UpKey = false;
var DownKey = false;
var RightKey = false;
var LeftKey = false;
var tank2_x;
var tank2_y;
var tank2_w = 30;
var tank2_h = 30;
var rad = Math.PI/180;

function init() {
    //canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = $('#myCanvas')[0].getContext('2d'); //sets the canvas as a jquery object to the variable 'context'
    WIDTH = $('#myCanvas').width();
    HEIGHT = $('#myCanvas').height();
    tank1_x = WIDTH * 1 / 4 - tank1_w / 2; //centre width TANK1
    tank1_y = HEIGHT * 1 / 4 - tank1_h / 2; //centre height TANK1
    tank2_x = WIDTH * 3 / 4 - tank2_w / 2; //centre width TANK2
    tank2_y = HEIGHT * 3 /4 - tank2_h / 2; //centre height TANK2
    setInterval('draw()', 25); //sets interval for draw method to repeat after
}
function clearCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT); // clears whole canvas
}

tank1 = function fillRect(x,y,w,h) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillRect(WIDTH*1/4, HEIGHT*1/4, tank1_w, tank1_h);
    context.endPath();
}

tank2 = function fillRect(x,y,w,h) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillRect(WIDTH*3/4, HEIGHT*3/4, tank2_w, tank2_h);
    context.endPath();
}

draw = function() { // redraws rectangle to canvas
    clearCanvas();
    //TANK1 ROTATION
    if (DKey) {
        var buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
        buffer.width = buffer.height = tank1_w*2;
        var bctx = buffer.getContext('2d');
        bctx.translate(tank1_x + tank1_w/2, tank1_y + tank1_h/2);
        bctx.rotate(5*rad);
        bctx.fillRect(tank1_x, tank1_y, tank1_w, tank1_h);
        ctx.drawImage(buffer, tank1_x, tank1_y);
    }
    else if (AKey) {
        context.save();
        context.clearRect(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        context.translate(tank1_x + tank1_w/2, tank1_y + tank1_h/2); //http://www.williammalone.com/briefs/how-to-rotate-html5-canvas-around-center/ and StackOverflow
        context.rotate(5*rad); //Translates origin of rotation to centre of block, then rotates 5 degrees
        context.fillRect(tank1_x, tank1_y, tank1_w, tank1_h); //Redraw TANK1
        context.rotate(-5*rad);
        context.translate(-tank1_x - tank1_w/2, -tank1_y - tank1_h/2); //Translates origin of rotation back to top left of canvas
        context.restore();
    }
    //TANK1 MOVEMENT
    if (WKey) tank1_y -= 5;
    else if (SKey) tank1_y += 5;
    if (tank1_x <= 0) tank1_x = 0;
    if ((tank1_x + tank1_w) >= WIDTH) tank1_x = WIDTH - tank1_w;
    if (tank1_y <= 0) tank1_y = 0;
    if ((tank1_y + tank1_h) >= HEIGHT) tank1_y = HEIGHT - tank1_h;
    context.fillRect(tank1_x,tank1_y,tank1_w,tank1_h);

    //TANK2 ROTATION
    if(RightKey) {
        context.translate(tank2_x + tank2_w/2, tank2_y + tank2_h/2);
        context.rotate(5*Math.PI/180);
        context.translate(-tank2_x - tank2_w/2, -tank2_y - tank2_h/2);
    }
    else if (LeftKey) {
        context.translate(tank2_x + tank2_w/2, tank2_y + tank2_h/2);
        context.rotate(-5*Math.PI/180);
        context.translate(-tank2_x - tank2_w/2, -tank2_y - tank2_h/2);
    }
    //TANK2 MOVEMENT
    if (UpKey) tank2_y -= 5;
    else if (DownKey) tank2_y += 5;
    if (tank2_x <= 0) tank2_x = 0;
    if ((tank2_x + tank2_w) >= WIDTH) tank2_x = WIDTH - tank2_w;
    if (tank2_y <= 0) tank2_y = 0;
    if ((tank2_y + tank2_h) >= HEIGHT) tank2_y = HEIGHT - tank2_h;
    context.fillRect(tank2_x,tank2_y,tank2_w,tank2_h);
}

function onKeyDown(event) {
    //TANK1 (WASD Keys)
    if (event.keyCode == 68) DKey = true;
    else if (event.keyCode == 65) AKey = true;
    if (event.keyCode == 87) WKey = true;
    else if (event.keyCode == 83) SKey = true;
    //TANK2 (Arrow Keys)
    if (event.keyCode == 39) RightKey = true;
    else if (event.keyCode == 37) LeftKey = true;
    if (event.keyCode == 38) UpKey = true;
    else if (event.keyCode == 40) DownKey = true;
}

function onKeyUp(event) {
    //TANK1
    if (event.keyCode == 68) DKey = false;
    else if (event.keyCode == 65) AKey = false;
    if (event.keyCode == 87) WKey = false;
    else if (event.keyCode == 83) SKey = false;
    //TANK2
    if (event.keyCode == 39) RightKey = false;
    else if (event.keyCode == 37) LeftKey = false;
    if (event.keyCode == 38) UpKey = false;
    else if (event.keyCode == 40) DownKey = false;
}

$(document).keydown(onKeyDown);
$(document).keyup(onKeyUp);

init();
});
```

I've tried using a buffer and that didn't work for me and neither did clearing then rotating the canvas, redrawing the first tank and then rotating the canvas back (so the tank rotates) and then redrawing the rest as it was. I don't know what else to do.

At the moment I've got what I tried with the buffer in Tank1's rotation and the canvas rotation in Tank2's.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to put `context.save();` before and `context.restore();` after the actual rotation of tank2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the *absolute* rotation for the tank and use this instead of accumulating the transformation matrix (just add/subtract rotation angle to this value instead, f.ex a `tank1_rotation`). If you keep it relative you have to transform everything in the scene relative which makes it complicated to keep track of things.

After you have rotated and drawn the tank, this approach/change will allow you to simply call the following to keep everything in check:

```
context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

This will reset the transformation matrix to initial state, and is many times faster than using save/restore.

Next time you draw the tank you just use the angle you have stored, draw and repeat the above.

Answer (score 0):

After trying these I found the most straightforward thing to do (I'm a maths student) was to manually draw all of the points of the tank and use a matrix to rotate each point accordingly.

```
drawTank1 = function(x, y, w, h) {
    cos1 = Math.cos(tank1_angle);
    sin1 = Math.sin(tank1_angle);
    var centre_x = tank1_x;
    var centre_y = tank1_y;
    var corner1_x = - 20 * cos1 - 20 * sin1 + centre_x;
    var corner1_y = 20 * sin1 - 20 * cos1 + centre_y;
    var corner2_x = - 20 * cos1 + 20 * sin1 + centre_x;
    var corner2_y = 20 * sin1 + 20 * cos1 + centre_y;
    var corner3_x = 20 * cos1 + 20 * sin1 + centre_x;
    var corner3_y = - 20 * sin1 + 20 * cos1 + centre_y;
    var corner4_x = 20 * cos1 - 20 * sin1 + centre_x;
    var corner4_y = - 20 * sin1 - 20 * cos1 + centre_y;
    var corner5_x = 5 * cos1 - 20 * sin1 + centre_x;
    var corner5_y = - 5 * sin1 - 20 * cos1 + centre_y;
    var corner6_x = 5 * cos1 - 30 * sin1 + centre_x;
    var corner6_y = - 5 * sin1 - 30 * cos1 + centre_y;
    var corner7_x = - 5 * cos1 - 30 * sin1 + centre_x;
    var corner7_y = 5 * sin1 - 30 * cos1 + centre_y;
    var corner8_x = - 5 * cos1 - 20 * sin1 + centre_x;
    var corner8_y = 5 * sin1 - 20 * cos1 + centre_y;
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = '#00FF00';
    context.moveTo(corner1_x, corner1_y);
    context.lineTo(corner2_x, corner2_y);
    context.lineTo(corner3_x, corner3_y);
    context.lineTo(corner4_x, corner4_y);
    context.lineTo(corner5_x, corner5_y);
    context.lineTo(corner6_x, corner6_y);
    context.lineTo(corner7_x, corner7_y);
    context.lineTo(corner8_x, corner8_y);
    context.lineTo(corner1_x, corner1_y);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}
```

Thank you all for your help and suggestions